# How to find stock turning price points

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, financial, stockquotes

Let me know how to find turning price points in stock data in SQL. for example we have following data columns and N rows:

```
Date     |Price|
20150101 | 100  |
20150102 | 50   |
20150103 | 80   |
     .
     .
     .
201708027 | 200  |
```

and I want to find the turning points (date and price) , to understand clearly check following image.please help me how to find red points.
[image: Sample]

Comment: Do you want to forecast? Then you are looking for Holt-Winters-Brown smoothing and "changepoint analysis" (as you need the inflection points on the smoothed curve to filter out the noise).

Comment: @Koshinae Actually I am looking for the past buy and sell price and then implement those for future stock price

Comment: You still have to smooth the curve to find the inflection points.

Answer (score 5):

Using `SELF JOIN`:

```
SELECT cur.*
FROM tab cur
JOIN tab prev
  ON cur.date = prev.date + 1
JOIN tab next
  ON cur.date = next.date - 1
WHERE cur.price > prev.price AND cur.price > next.price;   -- peak
-- WHERE cur.price < prev.price AND cur.price < next.price; -- bottom
```

Using `LEAD` and `LAG` will be much more readable but they are available from `SQL Server 2012+`.

Comment: Based on the question, this is the right answer.  I would be surprised if there are quotes every day.  If so, the OP should accept this answer and ask *another* question, with more suitable sample data and a better explanation of what to do in the even of holidays and weekends.

Comment: @lad2025 thanks for your answer but it doesn't accurate enough to me.